# What do the two (double) vertical bars mean in this equation?

Tags: calculus, notation, vectors

Quoting the paper...

"The range difference equation between BR (R1) and transmitter (T) and any other receiver (Rj) has the following form:"

$$
c \cdot \Delta t_{ij} = \Delta d_{ij}
 = \left\|\vec{r_T} - \vec{r_{R1}} \right\|
 - \left\|\vec{r_T} - \vec{r_{Rj}} \right\|.
$$

Comment: $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ indicates a norm. It should be clear from the article what kind of norm is being used.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Writing $\lVert \vec{x} \rVert$ for a vector $\vec{x}$ is a standard notation for the *norm* of $\vec{x}$. The question is which is the norm in question (a usual choice is the Euclidean norm (or "$2$-norm"), the notion of distance we usually deal with in the "real" 3D world).

After *finding* the "article" you mention [1], where the equation you mention is Eq. (1), it is clear from reading the subsequent equations and paragraph (especially the one leading to Eq.(4), "*The least squares solution is in this case:*") that the norm considered is indeed the usual Euclidean norm
$$
\lVert \vec{x}\rVert = \sqrt{ \sum_{i} \vec{x}_i^2 }
$$

---

[1] Lukasz Zwirello, Tom Schipper, Marlene Harter, and Thomas Zwick, *UWB Localization System for Indoor Applications: Concept, Realization and Analysis,* Journal of Electrical and Computer Engineering, vol. 2012, Article ID 849638, 11 pages, 2012. [doi:10.1155/2012/849638](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jece/2012/849638/cta/)

Answer (score 0):

Double bars denote the magnitude (or length) of a vector.